# UK visa rejected three times

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, serial-refusals

My UK visa was rejected once in 2013 and twice in 2018. how should I apply again[image]

Comment: It's a terrible refusal. Doesn't seem fair. You want to attend your graduation. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Exactly, the student should decide where they want to graduate not the Home office.

Comment: @greatone I think you've misunderstood. It's not "I'm rejecting your application because you're just coming for a graduation ceremony." It's "I'm rejecting your application because the rest of your application isn't up to scratch and coming to a graduation ceremony isn't essential." Claiming to be a student and not giving any evidence of that was a big mistake.

Comment: Very relevant: [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/92121/11491).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I did submit my university record book and results sheet highlighting my resit subjects. But they have not taken that into consideration. What I don't understand is that every student is entitled to a graduation ceremony, how can the Home office decided if I need to attend my graduation ceremony or not, after the University send me a letter stating that I may attend the graduation ceremony. I have submitted emails and letters I have received from the university, which they have overlooked.

Comment: @SarahDissanayake I'm sorry but that's not how it works. You're not _entitled_ to enter any country that you're not a citizen of, and you can't enter a country without the permission of its government. Your university has told you that they'll let you into the ceremony if you come to the door; they can't let you into the country.

Comment: @DavidRicherby they didn't tell me at in the first refusal, they could have said there was no requirement to attend the graduation ceremony, which is a bit in human as I have paid their establishment and the Home office can't rule out my choice of attendance.Then I would have not applied. I have the same documentation sent for the both applications. But it's two different reasoning on both decisions. Which leads me to think that they have been biased,by quoting paras V4.1toV4.10 some of it is not relevant to me. How do you prove family ties? This is pure harsh racism.

Comment: @DavidRicherby in my second application they have evaluated me as a child. there is no consistency in the reasoning.

Comment: @SarahDissanayake No, really. It's the Home Office's job to decide whether or not you can come into the country. They can absolutely rule out your choice if your choice involved coming into the UK. I'm sorry you're having a terrible experience but you really do need to get to grips with the idea that countries get to decide who can or cannot come into them.

Answer (score 5):

I think the second bullet point makes it clear what you were missing in try #2

> You have submitted no information from your institution you are studying at

I would get a letter from the University about what you've been doing with them and include that in your next attempt.

Comment: I submitted my University record book and a result sheet highlighting my resit subjects. But that was not considered.

Comment: Hi, since there are two HE institutions involved here. Can you confirm which institution's record book / result sheet have you submitted? The one in UK or the one in Sri Lanka?

Comment: @SarahDissanayake I think they're looking for a letter from the University explaining what you're studying (i.e. "Sarah is studying a Masters of _________ and will complete her degree in 2019").

Comment: @B.Liu I submitted a letter from the UK university and record book from the Sri Lankan university.